# No query defined for that name [getUserByCity], Spring boot JPA NamedQuery from jpa-named-queries.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

There are many existing questions for this issue but my case is little different because I am trying to use named query in EntityManager.
I am trying to use named query(Defined in jpa-named-queries.properties not using @NamedQuery) in EntityManager but I am always getting No query defined for "name".

I have a class User

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER") // Note have column configuration also, not bring here to clear the code

class User{
   // My Properties

}
```

I have its repository which is extended from JpaRepository as well as from CustomUserRepository.
Here is my customer user repository.

```java
interface CustomUserRepository{
     List<User> executeQuery(String named, List<Object> params);
}

// its implementation class is something like this. 

class CustomUserRepositoryImpl implements CustomUserRepository{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;
    List<User> executeQuery(String named, List<Object> params){
          javax.persistence.Query namedquery = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(query);
        int[] idx = { 1 };
        parameters.stream()
            .filter(p-> p!=null)
            .forEach((m)->
                    namedquery.setParameter(idx[0]++, m));
        
        return namedquery.getResultList();

    }
}
```

I am using this `executeQuery` method from user repository.
Everything works fine if I declare named query above User class as follows.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER") // Note have column configuration also, not bring here to clear the code
@NamedQuery(name = "getUserByCity",
  query = "from User u where u.city= ?1")
class User{
   // My Properties

}
```

But not working If I am adding named query in `src/main/resources/META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties` with this I am getting no named query found for this key. following is my jpa-named-queries.properties file contents

```
getUserByCity=from User u where u.city= ?1

# also tried User.getUserByCity=from User u where u.city= ?1
```

Comment: Because that is dedicated for Spring Data JPA and not a regular JPA feature. So trying to access this through plain JPA won't work. Adding a method to your repository and just adding `@Query(name="getUserByCity")` would work as that is passed throuhg the dedicated Spring Data JPA classes.

Comment: I don't want to declare different method for each of my named query because I have so many named query so I want to execute them from a common method. Is there any other way in that case?

Comment: Define them either in `orm.xml` or as `@NamedQuery` which is native to JPA. Why the common method, what do you gain you still need to call that common method in all different places.

Comment: I call this common method from a rest endpoint which receives named query in query param.

Comment: Thanks for your point, orm.xml is working